# Android: Read text from view without accessibility?

Tags: android, parsing, accessibility, talkback, fitbit

Trying to make a service that takes the Fitbit app and creates an alert whenever the HR exceeds a specified zone.

Is it possible to parse the [view's](https://lh4.ggpht.com/AGYf6EAkFTeGRM4bOkraqu_1QKt7GgNjSehLOzRZ5tKv-BM5q7nfw8BkWNZyR4lI5w=h900) text without Talkback?

I'm trying to avoid Talkback because

1. It can't be turned on/off via the API
2. I don't want it to be on all the time
3. The text-to-speech is an unnecessary feature

And I can't use the Fitbit API because

1. You can't access the Bluetooth data directly, only the web service
2. You can't force the device to sync programmatically
3. And even if I use the web service, the data is delayed by Bluetooth + Sync + Download + any delay to limit overloading Fitbit servers + My (negligible) code processing

Comment: You could write your own [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html).

Comment: If you really mean "...without implementing an accessibility service", then the answer is no, for privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I completely misunderstood Talkback - I knew there were configurable/custom AccessibilityServices but for some reason I thought Talkback was the underlying framework...not just another service.

Thanks all.